# jQuery droppable : incorrect drop element in over event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I have implemented the scroll in a droppable container like below as droppable container doesn't have a scrollbar.

```
var maxTop = $('#drop_wrapper').height()+$('#drop_wrapper').offset().top;
var minTop = $('#drop_wrapper').offset().top;
var initialTop = $('#drop_wrapper').find('.dropps').first().offset().top;       
var scrollHeight = $('#drop_wrapper').find('.dropps').first().outerHeight();
var containerHeight = $('#drop_wrapper').outerHeight()
var firstLeft = $('#drop_wrapper').find('.dropps').first();
var lastLeft = $('#drop_wrapper').find('.dropps').last();

$('.draggs').draggable({
    addClasses: false,
    containment: 'main-container',
    delay: 250,
    revert: "invalid",
    revertDuration: 0,
    zIndex: 200,
    helper: "clone",
    scroll: false,
    cursor : 'move',        
    drag: function(event, ui){          
        if(ui.offset.top > maxTop && lastLeft.offset().top > containerHeight){                  
            document.querySelector('#drop_wrapper').scrollBy(0, scrollHeight);
    }else if(ui.offset.top < minTop && firstLeft.offset().top < initialTop ){
        document.querySelector('#drop_wrapper').scrollBy(0, -1 * scrollHeight);
    }
    }       
});
```

The scroll works fine in Chrome. The scroll will happen when we drag below or above the droppable container. Am highlighting the droppable containers by adding a class in the droppable "over" event and the same is removed in the "out"   event. In normal scenario i.e drag and drop without scroll, it is working fine.
In case where scroll happens, the 'this' object in over and out event doesnt give   the actual droppable node rather it gives the node that present in the corresponding position before scroll. The drop event gives the "this" object correctly in all the cases.

Can someone help?

I have added the sample in the below code pen. I have printed the "this" in over and drop event of droppable. once scrolled, the issue would happen.

[sample-code](https://codepen.io/_selva/pen/BPBmeZ/)

Comment: Please update your question with all your code.

Comment: @chŝdk : Added the sample